# Transaction integrity error when merging

Tags: drupal, duplicate-contacts

I have a vanilla CiviCRM setup which has been running for quite some time.
I'm currently running  4.7.14.   When attempting to merge records I get a transaction integrity error (see below for backtrace), which points to some sort of SQL error. Merging has worked in the past.  Any ideas what the problem could be?

Thanks!

```
#0 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(187):
CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921):
call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985):
PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: syntax error", -2, 16, (Array:2),
"UPDATE IGNORE  SET entity_id = 311 WHERE entity_id = 312
[nativecode=1064 ** ...")
#4 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575):
DB_Error->__construct(-2, 16, (Array:2), "UPDATE IGNORE  SET entity_id
= 311 WHERE entity_id = 312 [nativecode=1064 ** ...")
#5 [internal function](): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL,
-2, NULL, NULL, "UPDATE IGNORE  SET entity_id = 311 WHERE entity_id =
312 [nativecode=1064 ** ...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(224):
call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:8))
#7 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905):
PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#8 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905):
PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -2, NULL, NULL, "UPDATE IGNORE  SET entity_id =
311 WHERE entity_id = 312 [nativecode=1064 ** ...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#9 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933):
DB_common->raiseError(-2, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1064 ** You have an error
in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correspon...")
#10 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403):
DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#11 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216):
DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("UPDATE IGNORE  SET entity_id = 311 WHERE
entity_id = 312")
#12 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2438):
DB_common->query("UPDATE IGNORE  SET entity_id = 311 WHERE entity_id =
312")
#13 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1627):
DB_DataObject->_query("UPDATE IGNORE  SET entity_id = 311 WHERE
entity_id = 312")
#14 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(354):
DB_DataObject->query("UPDATE IGNORE  SET entity_id = 311 WHERE
entity_id = 312")
#15 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1297):
CRM_Core_DAO->query("UPDATE IGNORE  SET entity_id = 311 WHERE
entity_id = 312", TRUE)
#16 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/Merger.php(531):
CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("UPDATE IGNORE  SET entity_id = 311 WHERE
entity_id = 312", (Array:0), TRUE, NULL, TRUE)
#17 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Dedupe/Merger.php(1486):
CRM_Dedupe_Merger::moveContactBelongings("311", "312")
#18 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Merge.php(328):
CRM_Dedupe_Merger::moveAllBelongings("311", "312", (Array:20))
#19 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(435):
CRM_Contact_Form_Merge->postProcess()
#20 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Done.php(75):
CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#21 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203):
CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Done->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Merge),
"done")
#22 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103):
HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Merge),
"done")
#23 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351):
HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("done")
#24 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(113):
CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#25 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(284):
CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Contact_Form_Merge", "Merge Contact",
NULL)
#26 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84):
CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#27 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52):
CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#28 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(448):
CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#29 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("contact", "merge")
#30 /includes/menu.inc(527):
call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#31 /index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#32 {main}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved the issue.  It appears there was a null entry in  civicrm_custom_group associated with the contact table and deleting this fixed the problem